# What's wrong with this Java XML-Parsing code?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file and be able to insert a path and get the value of the field.

It looks as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLConfigManager {
    private Element config = null;

    public XMLConfigManager(String file) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            Document domTree;
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            domTree = db.parse(file);
            config = domTree.getDocumentElement();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            iae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getStringValue(String path) {
        String[] pathArray = path.split("\\|");
        Element tempElement = config;
        NodeList tempNodeList = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                if (tempElement.getNodeName().equals(pathArray[0])) {
                    System.out.println("First element is correct, do nothing here (just in next step)");
                }
                else {
                    return "**This node does not exist**";
                }
            }
            else {
                tempNodeList = tempElement.getChildNodes();
                tempElement = getChildElement(pathArray[i],tempNodeList);
            }
        }    
        return tempElement.getNodeValue();
    }
    private Element getChildElement(String identifier, NodeList nl) {
        String tempNodeName = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            tempNodeName = nl.item(i).getNodeName();
            if (tempNodeName.equals(identifier)) {
                Element returner = (Element)nl.item(i).getChildNodes();
                return returner;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The XML looks like this (for test purposes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<amc>
    <controller>
        <someOtherTest>bla</someOtherTest>
        <general>
            <spam>This is test return String</spam>
            <interval>1000</interval>
        </general>
    </controller>
    <agent>
        <name>test</name>
        <ifc>ifcTest</ifc>
    </agent>
</amc>
```

Now I can call the class like this

```
XMLConfigManager xmlcm = new XMLConfigManager("myConfig.xml");
System.out.println(xmlcm.getStringValue("amc|controller|general|spam"));
```

Here, I'm expecting the value of the tag `spam`, so this would be "`This is test return String`". But I'm getting `null`.

I've tried to fix this for days now and I just can't get it. The iteration works so it gets to the tag `spam`, but then, just as I said, it returns `null` instead of the text.

Is this a bug or am I just doing wrong? Why? :(

Thank you very much for help!

Regards, Flo

Comment: You may be going one step too further. If in your loop you get the children of all the elements in that | separated list, the last returned value would be the child of "spam", which does not exist.

Comment: Java has had an XPath library since JavaSE 5. It can be found in the `javax.xml.xpath` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned before me, you seem to be reinventing the concept of [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). You can replace your code with the following:

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/amc/controller/general/spam";
org.xml.sax.InputSource inputSource = new org.xml.sax.InputSource("myConfig.xml");
String result = xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource);
```

See also: [XML Validation and XPath Evaluation in J2SE 5.0](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/validationxpath/)

**EDIT:**

An example of extracting a collection with XPath:

```
NodeList result = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < result.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(result.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

The `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` interface is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html), and there are a few more examples in the [aforementioned article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/validationxpath/).

In addition, there are third-party libraries for XML manipulation, which you may find more convenient, such as [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) (suggested by [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728595/232235)) or [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/). Regardless of which library you use, you can leverage the quite powerful XPath language.

Comment: What if the part `<agent>...</agent>` gets copied and there are other values in the second tags name and ifc, how can I get a collection out of there? (all agents / for example all agent/name values)?

Comment: <agent><name>nameA</name></agent><agent><name>nameB</name></agent>

Comment: @Florian I added an example of extracting a collection.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `Node.getNodeValue()` - which is documented to return null when you call it on an element. You should call `getTextContent()` instead - or use a higher level API, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using `getNodeValue()` rather than `getTextContent()`.

Doing this by hand is an accident waiting to happen; either use the built-in XPath solutions, or a third-party library as suggested by @duffymo. This is not a situation where re-invention adds value, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wonder why you're not using a library like [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) and built-in XPath.  You're doing a lot of work with a very low-level API (WC3 DOM).

Step through with a debugger and see what children that `<spam>` node has.  You should quickly figure out why it's null.  It'll be faster than asking here.